# Using pool.map and functools.partial on matrices

Tags: python, partial, pool

So I have 2 matrices `A` and `B`, and indices `i` and `j`. I want to perform `some_function` on the matrices for a value `i` and several values of `j`. When I execute the following code:

```
def some_function(A,B,i,j):
    T=A[i,:]*B[:,j]
    return T
p=partial(some_function,A=A,B=B,i=1)
J=[2,3,4]
final=pool.map(p,J)
```

I get the error `TypeError: some_function() got multiple values for keyword argument 'A'`

Comment: reorganize your arguments so the one thats left as a variable (ie, `j`) is the first one.

Comment: I did and get the following error `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'some_function'`

Comment: that seems like a completely different problem altogether, looks like you are trying to call `some_function` from an import that doesn't have that function

Comment: realised I had to call pool(processes=N) just before the call to pool.map